# Opacity not working properly in javascript if it starts as 0.0

Tags: javascript, opacity

I have two divs on top of each other.  One has a background image and the other is an overlay that has opacity of 0.  With mouseover, the background changes and the overlay gets opacity 1 and on mouseleave the background goes back to the original and the overlay goes back to transparent.

Here is the weird part, if the opacity starts off at 0, it doesn't work.  If the opacity starts at 1 it works perfectly except that the overlay is visible when the page loads.  So what's going on and how do I get it to work starting with opacity of 0?

The HTML

```
<BODY>
<div id="corporate" onmouseover="changebg('contract.jpg', 1)"     
onmouseleave="changebg('corporate.jpg', 0)" 
onclick="changepage('corporate.html')"><div id="corporateoverlay">  
<h1>Corporate</h1></div>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The CSS

```
body {
background-color: #000000;
color: #ffff00;
}

h1 {text-align: center;}

#corporate {
width: 50%;
height: 250px;
clear: left;
float: left;
background-image: url('corporate.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
}

#corporateoverlay {
color: rgba(255,255,0,1)
}
```

The JS

```
function changebg (newpic, opac) {
var urlString = 'url(' + newpic + ')';
document.getElementById("corporate").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
document.getElementById("corporateoverlay").style.opacity = opac;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, color - specifies the color of the text so I don't know if you want to do that. 
Second, check here the compatibility http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/. Third you are changing opacity style.opacity and yet you used color: rgba(), opacity is another key in css. You should set-up a standard and then work with it because you are mixing things up.

Answer (score 0):

something like this? i just applied the opacity in the css separately from rgba.

```js
function changebg (newpic, opac) {
    var urlString = 'url(' + newpic + ')';
    document.getElementById("corporate").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
    document.getElementById("corporateoverlay").style.opacity = opac;
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
    color: gray;
}

h1 {text-align: center;}

#corporate {
    width: 50%;
    height: 250px;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    background-image: url('corporate.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
}

#corporateoverlay {
    color: gray;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="corporate" onmouseover="changebg('contract.jpg', 1)"     
    onmouseleave="changebg('corporate.jpg', 0)" 
    onclick="changepage('corporate.html')">
        <div id="corporateoverlay">  
            <h1>Corporate</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```